# rendering a TextView in a Bitmap for an android widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm building a widget which displays some text. By widget I mean the kind which lies on the desktop.

The problem is that I want to change text's font at runtime. There is several textview I would like, at runtime, to set the first as bold, the second blue and italic for example, etc.

I came up with this :

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setText(stringToDisplay);
tv.setTextColor(0xa00050ff);  // example
tv.setTextSize(30);           // example

Bitmap b = loadBitmapFromView(tv);
updateViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.id_of_the_imageview, b);
```

with

```
private static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v)
{
 Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height,      Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
v.draw(c);
return b;
}
```

but it wont work (NullPointerException on first line of loadBitmap), until I replace 
`v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height` by fixed sizes like 250, 50

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(250, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
// ...
v.layout(0, 0, 250, 50);
```

But that's not a good solution ...

so I tried this :

```
  LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View row = li.inflate(R.layout.widget_text, null);

  TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.id_of_the_textview);
```

`widget_text` being a layout similar to the displayed one but with TextViews instead of ImageViews, in the hope to get some size information out of it ..

but it's not working and I get this exception :

```
01-02 17:35:06.001: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11025): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
```

on the call to `Bitmap.createBitmap()`

so, someone could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Through RemoteViews you can still hide and show elements, so why not duplicate the text views for all font styles you might encounter?

something like:

```
widget.setViewVisibility(R.id.textview_italic,View.GONE);
widget.setViewVisibility(R.id.textview_bold,View.VISIBLE);
```

using images to display text should always be the last resort.

Comment: that's an option I overlooked, but how would you set the size? I can't possibly have different textviews for different sizes that would make a lot of textviews, considering I have 4 of them ... for 20 sizes that would make 320 textviews (bold/italic/boldItalic/normal) ... not even counting for font family and such things.

Comment: in that case, go for the last resort! This would be feasible only if it's just one message with a few styles of course. BTW if you're developing for recent versions of android only, you can add and remove views to RemoteViews dynamically, which could make this an option again. You also lose the multiplier of 4 I think. (and 80 unused layout entries don't really consume resources other than memory)

Comment: See @Daren's answer if you only plan to support later versions of android, but be aware that RemoteViews are quite restricted in what you can and cannot set.

Comment: that's nice but I still think the bitmap is the way to go, because it's the only way to be free. I mean if later I want font family or shadows with remoteViews it'll be hard/impossible

Answer (score 1):

You can set the size dynamically:

```
    float mySize = 10f;
    updateViews.setFloat(R.id.textview, "setTextSize", mySize);
```

Comment: nice. I was wondering what were all those methods with a parameter "methodName"